# Get source of group of links and save each one to certain file

Tags: php

i am trying to get a source of group of links and save the source of each link to separate file.

```
$urls = array(
              url1 => 'http://site1.com'
              url2 => 'http://site2.com'
              url3 => 'http://site3.com'
              );
}
$files = array(
               file1 => 'file1.html'
               file2 => 'file2.html'
               file3 => 'file3.html'
               );
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    ob_start();
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html

    echo $doc->saveHTML();

    $page = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_flush();
}
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fp = fopen("$file","w");
    fwrite($fp,$page);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

at this point i am stuck and it's not working

Comment: You're overwriting the variable `$page` each time through the first loop. So the second loop just writes the last page to each file.

Comment: @Barmar i can't get this point can u correct the code please?

Comment: How can you not get the point? Just step through the code by hand and it should be obvious. Each time through the loop you do `$page = ob_get_contents();`, which discards the contents of the previous URL. So when the loop is done, the variable just contains the contents from the last URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the URLs and write the files in the same loop.

```
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    file_put_contents($files[$i], file_get_contents($url));
}
```

There's no need to use `DOMDocument`, unless you really need to parse the HTML instead of just saving the source. And there's definitely no reason to use the `ob_XXX` functions, just assign the results directly to variables or pass them to functions.

And as design advice, when you have related data like the URLs and filenames, don't put them in separate arrays. Put them in a single, 2-dimensional array:

```
$data = array(array('url' => 'http://site1.com',
                    'file' => 'file1.html'),
              array('url' => 'http://site2.com',
                    'file' => 'file2.html'),
              array('url' => 'http://site3.com',
                    'file' => 'file3.html'));
```

This keeps all the related items close together, and you never have to worry about the two arrays getting out of sync as you update things.

Then you can loop over this one array:

```
foreach ($data as $datum) {
    $html = file_get_contents($datum['url']);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    // Do stuff with $doc
    $page = $doc->saveHTML($doc);
    file_put_contents($datum['file'], $page);
}
```

Comment: 1st thank u very much for your detailed response, then i have to use DomDocument as i need to parse the html and edit something in it before saving to file, so how to domdocument with you current code

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it with DOMDocument.